# javascript dice game - image does not change

Tags: javascript

Having a slight issue calling a math.random image for a dice game. When I click the roll button the image does not change. I have the images saved where the .html file is. Any help is much appreciated!

Roll The Dice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dieImage;

    function start()
    {
        var button = document.getElementById(rollButton);
        button.addEventListener("click", rollDice, false);
        dieImage = document.getElementById("die1");
    }

    function rollDice()
    {
    setImage(dieImage);
    }

    function setImage(dieImg)
    {
    var dieValue = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);
    dieImg.setAttribute("src", "die" + dieValue + ".jpg");
    dieImg.setAttribute("alt", "dieImg with" + dieValue + "spots");

    if (dieValue == 6)
        {
        document.getElementById("sometext").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
    else
        {
        document.getElementById("sometext").innerHTML = "Roll Again";
        }

    }

    window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "#">
        <input id = "rollButton" type = "button" value = "Roll Dice">
    </form>
    <li>
        <img id = "die1" src = "die1.jpg" alt = "blankImage">
    </li>
    <div id = "sometext">Roll for a 6!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The only issue with the code above is this line:

```
var button = document.getElementById(rollButton);
```

Should read

```
var button = document.getElementById("rollButton");
```

The above change DOES cause the function to work, and the image to be updated.  Assuming all of your images are in fact in the right place, you will see them change.

As a note of encouragement, I would suggest you code in Firefox, and get Firebug.  With these tools, you can then utilize the Firebug console and/or Firefox's Web Developer Error Console.  These are tremendously useful for troubleshooting problems like this quickly.